# Why is Echolink copying the exe file to another drive letter everytime I launch it?

Tags: software, echolink

I have Echolink 2.0.908 installed in the default folder C:\Program Files (x86)\K1RFD\EchoLink
Every time I click on the shortcut to launch it, a copy of echolink.exe is created in the root of my G:drive.

Every time I delete it from my G:\ drive and relaunch it creates another copy. If a copy already exists then it does not attempt to create another one. There is some dialoque when it does this but it goes away too fast for me to catch it.

Why does it do that?

Comment: Check the shortcut properties to find out what it's actually running

Comment: Get an antivirus (windows does come with bitdefender, that's fine enough) and check your whole drive, too. Don't run Windows XP, if that's where this happens.

Comment: Like @hobbs-KC2G [commented](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/17245/why-is-echolink-copying-the-exe-file-to-another-drive-letter-everytime-i-launch/17252#comment28580_17245), please right-click on the Echolink shortcut icon and view the Properties; then post that here.

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows XP? 7? 10?

Comment: "There is some dialoque when it does this but it goes away too fast for me to catch it." How about using screencam software to capture it, then play it back frame-by-frame. Perhaps you'll see it then. You might have to do that several times until you capture the dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all copies of your Echolink program and install it from a reputable source. This sounds like a virus or worm.

From my experience, Echolink runs fine and the only files created are in the %temp% folder.